# What do I call a design with tinted elements on top of a photograph?

Tags: transparency, style-identification, photography

How can I call the below kind of designs (tinted elements on photograph) 
[image]

I want to know, because to use the terms in search and so.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific name for it, beyond what you already said: tinted/transparent elements superimposed on a photograph.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it could be consider a "DuoTone" of sorts but since it's most likely being accomplished via "color" blend mode, don't think anyone coined a term for it. I would say come up with a snazzy name. ;)

Comment: I think using the term "duotone' would add way more confusion than anything since this isn't even remotely a duotone.

Comment: I wouldn't say remotely but I do see your point. Yes, scratch the "duotone" term as to not add to confusion.

Comment: :) I can see why you'd think duotone works, but generally duotones do not involve different pixels - a duotone is customarily the same art with just a slight bump to offset a second color. Once you get into different art for each color, it's no longer a duotone. :) But just my opinion :)

Comment: I love a good fiery debate but let's just leave it for something important like "which dark beer is the best?"  ;)  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A "2 color design" or a  "[2 color design with overprint](https://www.google.com/search?q=multichannel%20design%20photoshop&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI59SciMLzyAIVSGMmCh0H5Ar3&biw=1044&bih=774#tbm=isch&q=2%20color%20design%20overprint)". That's unfortunately not an official term for this specific style but still close to what it is.

In printing, I would call this a "multi channel" design but that's not a search term that will help you much if you are looking for inspiration online or examples; this term is related to the technique to achieve this with spot colors in Adobe Photoshop, not the style itself. It can help you find some tutorials to prepare print-ready files though.

And for clients, unfortunately, you might need to use the term "duotone" **even though it's not really a duotone** as mentioned in the other answer. Or stick to multi channel and explain them what it is.